# What is the meaning of "He would have finished work"?

Tags: sentence-meaning, future-in-the-past

> A: It was half past five. Dad would have finished work.

Does that sentence mean there was an expectation that Dad was going to have finished work by half past five?

I found this sentence under the use of *future in the past* on some websites.

Answer (score 4):

You're right about the expectation.

All modals in English have two sets of meanings: the more familiar set is the *deontic* meaning, which is about the objective world, and about obligations and necessities. Deontic meanings of *would* are generally about futurity, or intention (including when it serves as the past of *will*).

*Epistemic* meanings are about our knowledge or assumptions. Epistemic meanings of *would* and *will* are about our expectations. So

> Dad will have finished work.

in most contexts means something like "I expect or conclude that Dad has finished work"; and

> Dad would have finished work.

is the backshifted version of that.

These uses of *will* and *would* are absolutely not "future" (or "future in the past"). But I'm afraid that people have been referring to *will* a "future tense" for a long time now.

Comment: Ack, I was composing my answer (I take too long) when I saw a new answer had been posted I went ahead and posted anyway. But I full agree with your interpretation.

Comment: As a side note, this construction is often used when talking about the dead. "If dad were still alive, he would be coming home for dinner right now". That's not to say you can't use it in more normal situations, but I frequently associate this tense with death.

Comment: @RobinClower: That is a completely different _would_, a conditional _would_. The OP's _would_ is a "future from the past's perspective" _would_.

Comment: @TonyK: The OP's _would_ is epistemic, and has nothing whatever to do with futurity.  I i first though that Robin's example was deontic; but on consideration  I think it is epistemic, though it is a different case from the OP's

Comment: @ColinFine: perhaps "future" was wrong; but it's future tense. As in "That'll be the postman" when the door bell rings. And in the past: "The doorbell was ringing. That would be the postman." (I'm sorry, but I don't know what deontic and epistmic mean here.)

Comment: @TonyK: I explained that in my answer. And, as I also said in my answer, "People have been referring to _will_ [as] a "future tense" for a long time now', though it is neither a tense nor necessarily an indicator of futurity.

Comment: @ColinFine: syntactically, it is a future tense. Semantically not always; but this is normal, isn't it? As it its opposite  number, "Were you leaving already?"

Comment: Syntactically, if it is a tense then so are "can ..", "should .." etc. They are syntactically indistinguishable.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sentence A means that the speaker expects dad to have finished work by 5:30. Since it is 5:30 at the time, I would not call this **future** in the past, but the expectation is clear.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Jeff Morrow, I don't see the OP's sentence as being a type of elliptical conditional. Despite the appearance of *would*, it is not a conditional sentence because there is no "if-clause" (protasi) present in the sentence and none is implied.

There is no uncertainty or probability when the speaker mentions the time. It  was half past five, so that *meant* their father was not at work.

Compare that sentence with this one

> Dad **would have finished** work (but he hadn't) if **it had been** 5.30 (but it wasn't).
> and
> If it had been 5.30 (but it wasn't), Dad would not have been working (but he was still working).

It was the **speaker's assumption** (a knowledge based on verified experience) that their father could not have been working at 5.30 PM because he always finished working before that hour.

Answer (score 0):

You have the idea. I am not sure I would explain it as a past future. I might prefer to explain it as a past conditional with ellipsis.

> It was half past five. [If things were progressing normally,] Dad would have left work.

> It was half past five. [Unless something quite unusual had happened,] Dad should have left work.

It is absolutely true that “would” and “should” are past forms of “will” and “shall” (just as “could” and “might” are past forms of “can” and “may”), but modal verbs such as those have special rules. The main use of those modals in modern English is expressing conditionals that **are often implied rather than explicit**.

Comment: I see the OP's sentence as the past form of "*It **is** half past five. Dad **will** have left work.*" Do you see my sentence as an implied conditional as well?

Comment: @gotube Yes, that is exactly how I see it. The meaning is “given that it is half past five right now,  Dad probably either is currently leaving or else has recently left work.” It does not mean that “given that it is now half past five, Dad will leave work sometime within the next year unless he dies in the meantime.” Most statements about the future are in fact conditional statements because the future is unknowable. I think my approach is easier for students to understand. Talking about the “past future” is not an intuitively comprehensible concept.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd never thought of it that way, but it makes intuitive sense, and explains why "will" is used. Now that I think about it, the sentence really does mean, "He has left work, probably", with no past-of-future aspect at all. +1

Comment: @JeffMorrow what is your opinion on sentence B? Do you still think it’s a third conditional?  Here is the sentence. B: I phoned at six o'clock. I knew he would have got home by then. This one can’t be past conditional in my opinion.

Comment: @gotube I suspect that people like you and me who answer questions  about English are perhaps **too** knowledgeable about the history of the language to take into account that learners need something that is psychologically  relevant to understanding current usage. I also post at a math site (though not a mathematician) and am frequently surprised how often mathematicians do not see where the **psychological** barriers are for students. Thank you for litening to my point of view.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Hmmm... though if it's a conditional about the past, then "will" isn't necessary at all, like "*If all has gone normally, he **is** home now*". The "will" is not there just because of the conditional meaning

Comment: @ChhiringTenjiSherpa First, I am expressing my view on what is easiest to comprehend. I cannot articulate any way to make sense of the notion of a “past future.” If you find my explanation weird, please ignore it. Second, “I knew he would be home” makes no sense although I admit people say things like that, just as they say many other nonsensical things. Either “I knew that he was at home” or “I expected that he was already at home” make sense. But there is no implication of futurity in the original statement. In short, I am saying that the notion of past future is not particularly helpful.

Comment: @gotube You are correct. The use of modals like “will” merely act as signals of conditions, but the conditions are often implied. Implicit conditions make signals about conditionality really important. Anyway, I do not want to argue; I am offering an explanation that I hope people find helpful. Anyone who does not find it helpful as a guide to what people intend to convey should promptly forget I ever wrote it.

Comment: I don't see the sentence being conditional. It is stating a fact, that the speaker's father finished working some time around 5.30. It *was* half past five, **so** that meant he had finished work. It's a prediction looking from the past.

Comment: @Mari-Lou I think that your interpretation may have been what was intended, but it is not how  a careful user of English would express it. To assert a known fact. “It was half past five so Dad had left work” or “It was half past five so Dad was leaving work” imply no uncertainty and are statements of alleged fact. The use of “would” is not a statement about something expected to happen after 5:30. It is expressing mild uncertainty rather than futurity. In that sense, it is is implying something like “if the situation were normal.” **You skillfully** expressed certainty with “had left.”

Comment: Unfortunately comments cannot be edited when 5 minutes have expired. Maybe "a prediction looking back at the past” is clearer? As for expressing certainty, a speaker can  use "must" or "had to" as in "*He **must have finished** work / **had to have finished** work*

Comment: @Mari-LouA I do not like to argue. In terms of explanation, I find terms like “past future” unintuitive. And I find most assertions about the future to be necessarily contingent. I do not agree that “must have” is a synonym for “did.” The former expresses great confidence, what some people call “moral certanty; the latter expresses a fact. Proper use of modals permits great subtlety in English. But I shall not argue about this any further. You have your view. I have mine.

Answer (score -2):

It means the dad died at work or otherwise did not go to work. Would have means the condition never happened. (coulda, woulda, shoulda). So he either did not go to work or was not present at work at 5, or he died at work and was unable to meet the condition of finishing work.